# Two section layout with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a two section bootstrap layout work for desktop screens that turns into one section for mobile.

See codepen:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwWZKe

```
<div class="col-md-8 pull-right" style="background-color: #263;height:120px;">Section 1</div>
<div class="col-md-8 pull-right" style="background-color: #299;height:30px;">Section 2</div>

<div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="background-color: #999;height:50px;">Section 3</div>
<div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="background-color: #623;height:80px;">Section 4</div>
<div class="col-md-8 pull-right" style="background-color: #222;height:80px;">Section 5</div>
```

Ideally I want these to be divided in two columns (section 3,4 on left and 1,2,5 on right). But I don't want to create two super columns:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">section3 , section 4</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">section 1, section 2, section 5</div>
</div>
```

since I want this order (section1-5) for mobile.

**EDIT:**

The expected order for desktop is:
3-4 (for left section) and 1-2-5 (for right section)
for mobile: 1-2-3-4-5
The Divs are of varying height and I am looking to get them stacked with no spaces.

**UPDATE**

So I tried another approach:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
  <div style="background-color: #263;height:120px;">Section 1</div>
  <div class="" style="background-color: #299;height:30px;">Section 2</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
  <div style="background-color: #999;height:50px;">Section 3</div>
  <div class="" style="background-color: #623;height:280px;">Section 4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4" style="background-color: #222;height:80px;">Section 5</div>
```

where I join the blocks that go together, but I still have an issue of spacing on right section before Section 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it finally worked:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pymNRm

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-right">
  <div style="background-color: #263;height:120px;">Section 1</div>
  <div class="" style="background-color: #299;height:30px;">Section 2</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-left">
  <div style="background-color: #999;height:50px;">Section 3</div>
  <div class="" style="background-color: #623;height:280px;">Section 4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-right" style="background-color: #222;height:80px;">Section 5</div>
```

I had to combine the blocks that go together and use pull-right and pull-left

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use multiple instances of `col-<size>-<n>` classes.  xs for mobile, and md or lg for desktop.  And idk if you meant to ask for 1-3-5 and 2-4, but that's what I did.  This solution only works properly if the divs all have identical height.  Hope this helps.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZwPGo

Comment: I'm sorry that's not what I'm looking for. I'm familiar with varying screen sizes, order and height are important (updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to investigate the push / pull method but not the way you have it already - investigate the following syntax:

eg:"col-md-push-3" or "col-sm-pull-6"; etc

this will let you move the divs around to a different order on different viewports. Just using pull-right will apply a float:right to each div - not the effect you are after

The push class will move the div to the right while the pull class will move  the div to the left. You can therefore have a div that is on the left of the screen in a wider viewport, to the left on a small viewport and  stack in the desired order on a mobile (-xs- size)

Comment: thanks i tried that approach (see my update on the question above). But still the spacing is not solved.